# "Die Sonne scheint den Kindern auf die Köpfe. " Why do we use dative followed by a non-dative?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative

I saw it on [link to youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rdbe8G9qRaM) the following sentence :

> Die Sonne scheint den Kindern auf die Köpfe.

The sentence appears at 0:47. It seems like "den Kindern" here is a dative case. But why is it so?
Also, "auf die Köpfe" is non-dative. But shouldn't it be dative? As it is indicating the position. Shouldn't it be "auf der Köpfe"?

Comment: I don't understand, why you consider the dative to possess locking powers. Actually you can have all cases in the same sentence: *Ich (nominative) schenke dir (dative) das Auto (accusative) meines Vaters (genitive)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Scheinen* is intransitive, so there can't be an accusative object.

Dative indicates the receiver or the beneficiary of an action. This is the case here: The children get the light from the sun.

(As a side note, like many verbs *scheinen* can be turned into a transitive verb by adding the prefix be-. That would be *Die Sonne bescheint den Kindern die Köpfe*, a somewhat stilted but valid German sentence.)

*Auf die Köpfe* indicates direction, not position: The sunlight goes from the sun to the heads of the children. That's why it's accusative.

Dative would be *auf den Köpfen*, not *auf der Köpfe*. That would mean that the sun is placed on the children's heads, which obviously would be nonsense.

Comment: And since each child usually has only one head, "...scheint den Kindern auf den Kopf" would be even more idiomatic

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf That seems to be a bad translation from English, which insists that multiple kids must have multiple heads - German is simpler here and assumes the receiver can imagine that...